Can't connect to localhost websocket with iOS simulator
I have a basic websocket server on 127.0.0.1:5000, and i have a basic app running on a simulator using Swift's native implementation URLSessionWebSocketTask to connect to ws://localhost:5000.
Problem is, I am not able to connect the app to the localhost, I can connect the app to websockets like https://socketsbay.com/test-websockets, and if I update the iOS websocket implementation to use socket.io, I can get the app to connect to my localhost.
Why can't i use Swift's native implementation to connect to my localhost.
basic connection code:
    let url = URL(string: "ws://localhost:5000")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webSocketTask = URLSession.shared.webSocketTask(with: request)
    webSocketTask.delegate = self
    webSocketTask.resume()


localhost sometimes does not resolve the way you mean it to. Test this with 127.0.0.1 if that's what you've bound to with your server.
Since you're not using TLS here (i.e. "ws" rather than "wss"), you may be running into issues with App Transport Security. Make sure you've authorized localhost as an ATS exception.

ive tried with 127.0.0.1 with no luck either, and yes ive added localhost and 127.0.0.1 as an ATS exception. I've just gone ahead with using socket.io. I've a feeling its something to do with the handshake, but I don't know enough to debug that.
